# Neo4j:Retrieve first all first level nodes and then retrieve second level nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There is a neo4j graph which has more than one level. I want to retrieve a node first with its first level nodes and, after retrieving all first level nodes, I want to retrieve the second level nodes.

I have written the following query.

```
match(node{name:'some name'})-[r1]-(a)

optional match(a)-[r2]-(b)

return node,a,b
```

But the above query will first match first level node if the given node connected with second level node then it will retrieves all the second level connected nodes and after that come to first level node again and continue the process.(depth first approach).

I need it to do it like breadth first approach.

Comment: You mean you want to run two queries?

Answer (score 0):

Your language implies that you have some kind of hierarchy to me and that you probably want to add direction to your query. The other thing you want to do is use the `with` statement to take a result from your first query and use it as a starting point for your second query.  Using direction in your second query is import as without it the `a` nodes you match first will just match back against your original start node.  The `coalesce` function just takes care of instances where a has no child.

```
match (start {name : 'some name'})-->(a)
with a
optional match a-->b
return a, coalesce(null, 'no child')
```